# How to automatically append "end" to ruby code blocks in vim?

Tags: ruby, vim

This is a feature I miss from Textmate.  When you type out a def, if, block, etc. and hit enter, the editor automatically appends "end" to the code block and puts the cursor in between.

How do I set this up in vim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a plugin that does just that: [*endwise.vim*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2386).

Answer (score 3):

Two vim plugins come to mind that get a lot of recommendations:

- [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). See the [screencast](http://vimeo.com/3535418) for an overview.
- [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567)

I'll also recommend the [Surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) and [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugins as being really useful. And, I just just started working with [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) and it looks useful too.

Comment: For those looking for an out-of-the-box solution, snipmate didn't automatically add `end` to `do` blocks, whereas endwise did.